# Is array.push() O(1) in Haxe?

Tags: data-structures, arraylist, haxe

Many language has a standard type which can resize itself when needed, like C++'s `vector<T>` or C#'s `ArrayList<T>`. In Haxe, however, I don't see such a data structure.

Does `Array` in Haxe work this way? Can it add/remove the last element in (amortized) O(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this of course depends on the platform-specific implementation of `Array`, but it is safe to assume that `push` has amortized O(1) as that's pretty straight forward to accomplish (the neko implementation shows that rather nicely).

On all platforms that come with a dynamically sized Array with support for sparseness Haxe uses those for implementation (AFAIK that's flash, js and php), but I guess if those ever showed poor metrics, they would be re-implemented.

I would note that there is also `List`, if random access is not important. But on some platforms it is never faster than `Array`, only smaller.